# Stuck at converting integers into romans

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, integer, roman-numerals

I'm trying to convert integers into roman numerals using for loop. I started the code, but I'm currently stuck here, I don't know what to do(getting errors all the time). If anyone has any idea about how to continue this code, help would be much appreciated.

```
roman_digits = {1000: "M", 900: "CM", 500: "D", 400: "CD", 100: "C", 90: "XC", 50: "L", 40: "XL", 10: "X", 9: "IX", 5: 'V', 4: "IV", 1: "I"}

empty = ""
rand_num = 153

for nums, alpha in roman_digits.items():
    if rand_num <= nums:
        empty += alpha
        rand_num -= nums

print(empty)
```

this code is not working

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you would get an explicit Exception in this code. Though, logically, `153` is less than `1000`, though the roman numeral representation is CLIII, without the `M` that your code would insert

Comment: `dict` is not an ordered collection in Python. Are you at all sure this algorithm is proceeding in the order you expect?

Comment: Yes, it should work fine until user input is not over 1000

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist since python 3.7 dict is ordered with insertion order.

Comment: When I add "rand_num -= nums" to the code, I'm getting ridiculous result

Comment: @Boendal but it's bad practice to rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm needs to alter the value of the input number at some point. For example, with input like `1053`, on the first iteration you will discover `M`. At this point you are no longer interested in the `1000` place — you need the rest — `53`. So you can add `M` to your output and continue on looking for `53`. Then you find `L` and continue looking for `3`. Something like this might get it going in a good direction:

```
def rn(rand_num):
    empty = ""

    while rand_num > 0:
        for nums, alpha in roman_digits.items():
            if rand_num >= nums:
                empty += alpha
                rand_num -= nums  # change rand_nums
                break

    return empty
```

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for the help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I adapted the code I found [HERE](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/class-exercises/python-class-exercise-1.php) to work outside of its class. The logic is all explained on the website.

```
rand_num = 153

val = [
    1000, 900, 500, 400,
    100, 90, 50, 40,
    10, 9, 5, 4,
    1
    ]
syb = [
    "M", "CM", "D", "CD",
    "C", "XC", "L", "XL",
    "X", "IX", "V", "IV",
    "I"
    ]
roman_num = ''
i = 0
while  rand_num > 0:
    for _ in range(rand_num // val[i]):
        roman_num += syb[i]
        rand_num -= val[i]
    i += 1
print(roman_num)
```